# Compare memberwise parameter packs of different lengths

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, parameter-pack

```
template <int... ValuesOrSentinals>
struct type {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct are_compatibles;
template <int... TVals, int... UVals>
struct are_compatibles<type<TVals...>, type<UVals...>>
    : public conjunction<bool_constant<sizeof...(TVals) == sizeof...(UVals)>,
                         bool_constant<((TVals == UVals) && ...)>> {};
```

Here I define a compatibility check between two parameter packs. The actual member check is more complicated than an equality check, so I can't fallback to `is_same<integer_sequence<int, TVals...>, integer_sequence<int, UVals...>>`. I must check each member on its own.

- `are_compatibles<type<1, 2>, type<1, 2>>::value == true;` compiles.
- `are_compatibles<type<1, 2>, type<2, 1>>::value == false` compiles.
- `are_compatibles<type<1, 2>, type<1>>::value == false` fails to compile because parameter packs are not the same length.

Is there a way to compare memberwise parameter packs of different lengths?

Comment: isn't `std::conjunction` a C++17 class? or you rolled out own implementation?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Fair enough. I'm running C++20 (as much as I can considering incomplete support). The main question is still C++11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, with Enabler:

```
template <int... ValuesOrSentinals>
struct type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename Enabler = void>
struct are_compatibles : std::false_type{};

template <int... TVals, int... UVals>
struct are_compatibles<type<TVals...>, type<UVals...>,
                       std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(TVals) == sizeof...(UVals)>>
    : std::bool_constant<((TVals == UVals) && ...)>
{};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fcc1fxWfj)

Answer (score 0):

Do it two phase.  First check same length, then second (which you only run if first passes) pairwise compares.

```
template<class...>struct always_false:std::false_type{};
template<template<class...>class Z>struct ztemplate{template<class...Ts>using apply=Z<Ts...>;};

template<class A, class B>
struct foo;
template<int...As, int...Bs>
struct foo<type<As...>,type<Bs...>>:
  std::conditional<
    sizeof...(As)==sizeof...(Bs),
    ztemplate<are_compatible>,
    ztemplate<always_false>
  >::type::template apply<type<As...>,type<Bs...>>
{};
```

or somesuch

Comment: Shouldn't `ztemplate` embrace the conditional instead of the other way around? Also, C++11.

Comment: Seems like `ztemplate` is used to delay template instantiation until we have asserted the expansion will work. Well. Maybe it could be done. Gonna work on it.

Comment: @alex yes.  You could also conditional the `type<>` argument(s) instead.  I just used ztemplate to pass templates around as types.

Comment: Yep. In the end, the core of most solutions will be to use template template parameters and delay instantiation until it has been deemed valid. I wonder which approch is best...

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Yakk's answer, here is a simpler version to delaying instantiation of the potentially incorrect pack expansion:

```
template <bool Test, template <typename...> typename TrueType,
          template <typename...> typename FalseType>
struct late_binding_conditional {
  template <typename... Ts>
  using instantiate = typename TrueType<Ts...>::type;
};
template <template <typename...> typename TrueType,
          template <typename...> typename FalseType>
struct late_binding_conditional<false, TrueType, FalseType> {
  template <typename... Ts>
  using instantiate = typename FalseType<Ts...>::type;
};
```

Using `late_binding_conditional` is left as an exercise for the reader as it depends on the specific use case.

This could be used in any situation where using a type_trait may result in an invalid template instantiation. It's therefore not limited to pack expansions.